# Differential operator with absolute sign?

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

From Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis - Schlag, Muscalu
There is a operator denoted by $|D|$, where $D$ is a convenient notation for derivative operator. What does $|D|$ mean?

Is it $|Df|$? of $D|f|$? or something else?

I've googled but I haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: you could multiply the Fourier transform by $|\xi|$ instead of $\xi$ where $\xi$ is the frequency variable.

Comment: Like how? In this book the fractional derivative is defined as $D^\alpha \hat{f}=(|\xi|^\alpha\hat{f})\check{}$.

Comment: if $\alpha=1$ that doesn't give differentiation in the normal sense

Comment: An absolute value sign around an operator usually means the operator norm.